# access word doc from javascript?

Tags: javascript, ms-word, activex, activexobject

I have tried to load (embed) the .doc file into the html page using object tag. And it doesn't show the word toolbar. My requirement is to allow the user to print the doc from print option in word.

Is there a possible way in javascript to enable the word toolbars??

And I have tried another approach using the ActiveXObject.. but this method opens the document in winword.exe.. is there a way to embed the .doc file through javascript..?

**EDIT:**
I was looking for other possibilities, but nothing works

1. Anybody got an idea about the list of params available for the Word ActiveX?
   Maybe that could contain the property to enable toolbars on load..
2. I used the below code to load .doc content to ActiveX Word Document control

   ```
   var objWord = new ActiveXObject("Word.Application");
   objWord.Visible=false;
   var Doc=new ActiveXObject("Word.Document");
   Doc=objWord.Documents.Add("c:\\test.doc", true);
   ```

   Is there a way to render the DOC element directly into HTML.. like putting this element in iframe or whatever??
3. I was assigning the iframe source property directly to the doc file, like this

   ```
   <iframe id="sam" src="c:\\test.doc">
   ```

   this loads the doc into browser, but this prompt to open a downloader window.

I'd really appreciate any hint that lead me to some direction.

Comment: can u suggest the best place to start with for automating word doc generation in javascript ( i need different header and footer oin same doc so how to section break and unlink from previous automatically)

Answer (score 0):

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>MSWORD App through JavaScript</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<script>
var w=new ActiveXObject('Word.Application');
var docText;
var obj;
if (w != null)
{
w.Visible = true; // you can change here visible or not 
obj=w.Documents.Open("C:\\A.doc");
docText = obj.Content;
w.Selection.TypeText("Hello");
w.Documents.Save();
document.write(docText);//Print on webpage

/*The Above Code Opens existing Document
set w.Visible=false
*/
/*Below code will create doc file and add data to it and will close*/
w.Documents.Add();
w.Selection.TypeText("Writing This Message ....");
w.Documents.Save("c:\\doc_From_javaScript.doc");
w.Quit();
/*Don't forget
set w.Visible=false */

}
```

Comment: this is wat i have said actually.. 

but this method opens the document in winword.exe.. is tehre a way to embed the .doc file through javascript..?

i dont want to open the doc in standalone winword.exe.. it must be opened within a browser with all the tollbars enabled.

Enbedding .doc using the object doesnt show the word toolbar. this  is the sample code i ve tried

<object width="800" height="4000px" id="oWord" data="samtest.doc" classid="clsid:00020906-0000-0000-C000-000000000046">


Cheers

Ramesh Vel

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there's no way to force this to be opened in a browser. Simply because the server will send the mime type of a word document, from that point on it is up to the client to decide what to do with it and a majority are set to download. There are however some registry tweaks that you can do on a client machine to force the client machine to view word documents inside of internet explorer.